Why doesn't the dropdown for "Kontakti" work?
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        #navbar {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        #navbar a {
            display: inline-block;
            color: #333;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px 30px; /* Increased padding for bigger buttons */
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 20px; /* Increased font size */
        }
        
        #navbar a:hover {
            background-color: orange;
            color: white;
        }
        
        .dropdown {
            display: inline-block; /* Change float to display */
            position: relative; /* Add position relative for dropdown positioning */
        }
        
        .dropdown .dropbtn {
            font-weight: bold;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            color: #333;
            padding: 20px 30px; /* Increased padding for bigger buttons */
            background-color: inherit;
            font-family: inherit;
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 20px; /* Increased font size */
        }
        
        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            z-index: 1;
            text-align: left; /* Align dropdown content to the left */
        }
        
        .dropdown-content a {
            color: #333;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }
        
        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
        }
        
        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body align="center" bgcolor=#BCD9DD>

<div id="navbar">
    <a href="AB1.html" class="active">Info</a>
    <a href="Ratslaukums.html">Galerija</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Kontakti</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Adrese</a>
            <a href="#">Tālrunis</a>
            <a href="#">E-pasts</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="https://www.melngalvjunams.lv/lv">Par mums</a>
</div>

Don't mind the large text, but firstly I finnaly centered all of that on top. Now the problem is, I don't know why the dropdown isn't working.
I tried a lot of things, because before I centered it, all worked fine. I don't know what to do and I'm seeking help from You. Before I centered the text, everything worked fine. Why isn't it working now?

Remove overflow:hidden from the #navbar
#navbar {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;        
        text-align: center;
    }

